# Using jquery/javascript to move a hidden menu bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure why the following doesn't work. I inspected and it successfully changes the class names but when I click on tab it doesnt move.

```
var main=function() {
    $('.uptab').click(function() {
        $('.headbar').animate({
            top: '10px'
        }, 600);
        $('.tab').animate({
            top: '45px'
        }, 600);
        $('.tab').removeClass('uptab');
        $('.tab').addClass('downtab');
    });
    $('.downtab').click(function() {
        $('.headbar').animate({
            top: '-40px'
        }, 600);
        $('.tab').animate({
            top: '-5px'
        }, 600);
        $('.tab').removeClass('downtab');
        $('.tab').addClass('uptab');
    });
};


$(document).ready(main)
```

Comment: Can you paste your HTML or create a [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: A live example would be nice (plunker/jsfiddle).

Comment: just FYI, you should be chaining your jQuery.